# Webview2 website connect to audio has to be manually clicked

Tags: wpf, html5-audio, webview2

I am using wpf webview2 to build an app , the webview2 will navigate to my website which has one button to connect to audio , but i want to make it connect to audio automatically , so i tried use code like

document.getElementById("audioBtn").click();  to try to connect to audio.

But seems this doesn't work, i still have to manually click the button rather than trigger the click by script. (maybe due to some browser security policy ?)

I also tried to auto allow the permission in webview2

`private void CoreWebView2_PermissionRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2PermissionRequestedEventArgs e) {           e.State = CoreWebView2PermissionState.Allow; }`

So how can i automatically connect to audio ?  Both the WPF application and the web application is mine.. so there is no security risk..

thank you so much...

I also tried to auto allow the permission in webview2

`private void CoreWebView2_PermissionRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2PermissionRequestedEventArgs e) {           e.State = CoreWebView2PermissionState.Allow; }`

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying that click before the content is properly loaded, in which case there will be no document there or element in it.

Assuming this is the problem then you can handle the navigation completed event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.navigationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1245.22

Something like:

```
wv2.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += (s, at) =>
{
    wv2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('audioBtn').click();");
};
```

Before you navigate

Comment: no, I tried that click after the document is ready, i used a js timer , after 6 seconds to trigger js button click.
It's due to the browser security detection.. seems it can only connect audio after detecting human interaction.